# Transform gradient descent with L2 regularisation to code

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gradient-descent

I am stuck on writing this line of code - it's a really simple line of code that is tripping me up.

I'm supposed to write the gradient descent function with parameters- weights, X, y, train_len (defined as number of rows of X), alpha, learning_rate and num_iter.

[The first derivative of the loss function wrt to weight is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBWGt.png)
I've tried writing the code like this:

```
for i in range(0, n_iter):

  weights = weights - learning_rate * (np.multiply(-2, np.dot(X.transpose(), y - np.dot(X, weights))) + np.multiply(2*alpha, weights))

return weights
```

Unfortunately I'm ending up with nan when I try using the gradient descent function.

Comment: General tips: write `X.T` instead of `X.transpose()` and `alpha*weights` instead of `np.multiply()`.

Comment: When do you get `nan`s? After one step or many? Is what you gave the only code you have within the `for` loop?

Comment: @cheersmate I need to check when I got the nans, and yes whatever I’ve inside the for loop is in here.

Comment: But shouldn't you re-compute `X` during each iteration? You need to do a forward-pass before doing a backward-pass...

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, n_iter):
  first_derivative = -2 * np.dot(X.T, y - np.dot(X, weights)) + 2 * alpha * weights
  weights = weights - (learning_rate / train_len) * first_derivative
return weights
```

Turns out I forgot to divide by the number of training examples.